# Php downloading PDF fails, it shows weird characters instead

Tags: php, pdf, download

i've got this situation.
I want to allow a user to download a PDF file.
It works fine in my localserver. Nevertheless, when i upload the script to another server for production, it shows weird characters instead of donwloading the PDF file.

The characters that appear look like the following:

%PDF-1.6 %���� 41 0 obj <>stream h�L�� �0�W��`��V��<���7�Pf^Zi+loo��!?$�KjH(�����6��Ǻ�I��0ӓ����g�\���ln)g�So��.ldT��y���2:>stream h�,���0��W�����]P'����x��Bb�܁�w��}��l �u؇W���:����C����QGs5�(x1�wL���K��YUL$�5P͔@��5���}��|��=����w��O���J���� 0��1� endstream endobj 43 0 obj <>stream h޴�MO�

...

and so on ...

at the end this is shown:

3"��j����K�n���j��Z��9���vb~��Y� ��p�(ء> endobj 44 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[]/Info 4 0 R/Length 156/Root 1 0 R/Size 45/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream h�bb&FV>& ���}���?��v��'#�-���~S7��T{V�R��"�����!q3H�0�D���5��e0�&#A��40�H2�y��L`{�ْ`6X��;X��Ȁd� 0�7���H��t��X��d���`&# endstream endobj startxref 142999 %%EOF

And here is part of the code i am using.

```
$dir='cartas/'.$filename.'.pdf';
if(file_exists($dir)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dir));
    //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    //readfile($dir);
    echo file_get_contents($dir);
}else{
    exit('<p style="color: red;">The file does not exist.</p>');
}
```

Why is this happening? Can anyone out there shed some light?

Comment: Remove `Content-Transer-Encodind: binary` header

Comment: hello! i removed that but it still does not work :/

Comment: Remove all headers but the `content-type` one

Comment: I tried removing all the headers but the content-type. It still shows those weird characters :( Does it possibly have to do with folder permissions?

Comment: I don't think so. This is all your code right?

Comment: mind replacing `readfile($dir);` by `echo file_get_contents($dir);` ?

Comment: Salut, Loïc! I tried file_get_contents and nope, it just does not work :(

Comment: have you found a solution for that problem ???